# initializing a boolean array in java

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I have this code

```
public static Boolean freq[] = new Boolean[Global.iParameter[2]];
freq[Global.iParameter[2]] = false;
```

could someone tell me what exactly i'm doing wrong here and how would i correct it? I just need to initialize all the array elements to Boolean false.
thank you

Answer (score 310, accepted):

> *I just need to initialize all the array elements to Boolean false.*

Either use `boolean[]` instead so that all values defaults to `false`:

```
boolean[] array = new boolean[size];
```

**Or** use [`Arrays#fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29) to fill the entire array with [`Boolean.FALSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#FALSE):

```
Boolean[] array = new Boolean[size];
Arrays.fill(array, Boolean.FALSE);
```

Also note that the array index is zero based. The `freq[Global.iParameter[2]] = false;` line as you've there would cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. To learn more about arrays in Java, consult [this basic Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: The second piece of code is beneficial for the case when we wanna initialize it (set it) to all true values. Great answer!

Comment: I'd rather inverse the variable name and use the default initialization with false values.

Comment: I am actually in favor of `Boolean[] array` as it allows you to have three states for each element: `true`, `false` and `null`, which is useful for cases where you want to note that something is "not processed".

Answer (score 21):

The array will be initialized to false when you allocate it.

All arrays in Java are initialized to the default value for the type. This means that arrays of ints are initialised to 0, arrays of booleans are initialised to false and arrays of reference types are initialised to null.

Comment: He's using `Boolean`, not `boolean`, so it will default to `null`.

Comment: Correct. I did not see that. Arrays.fill should do the trick.

Comment: Does this apply to all versions of Java?

Comment: @Spyre: Yes. This behavior is part of the definition of the language.

Answer (score 9):

Arrays in Java start indexing at 0. So in your example you are referring to an element that is outside the array by one.

It should probably be something like freq[Global.iParameter[2]-1]=false;

You would need to loop through the array to initialize all of it, this line only initializes the last element.

Actually, I'm pretty sure that false is default for booleans in Java, so you might not need to initialize at all.

Best Regards

Comment: He's using `Boolean`, not `boolean`, so it will default to `null`.

Answer (score 5):

They will be initialized to `false` by default. In Java arrays are created on heap and every element of the array is given a default value depending on its type. For `boolean` data type the default value is `false`.

Comment: He's using `Boolean`, not `boolean`, so it will default to `null`.

Comment: i meant to use boolean, my bad...sorry for the mislead

Answer (score 2):

public static Boolean freq[] = new Boolean[Global.iParameter[2]];

Global.iParameter[2]:

It should be const value

Comment: this is not true. could be variables as well. the problem is that you are using Global.iParameter[2] to access the array. but the indices are going from 0 until only Global.iParameter[2]-1 !!

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that Boolean is an *object* and boolean is an *primitive*.

- *Object* default value is null;
- *boolean* default value is false;